# How to use jquery selector in class with white spaces?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, bootstrap-4

I have the Html code below:

```
<span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
```

I want to toggle `class="fa fa-heart-o"` to `class="fa fa-heart"` on hover in all span with this class

```
$("span").filter(".fa.fa-heart-o").hover(function () {
  alert("hola");
  this.removeClass('fa fa-heart-o');
  this.addClass('fa fa-heart');
}, function () {
  alert("adios");
  this.removeClass('fa fa-heart');
  this.addClass('fa fa-heart-o');
  });
```

});

I've tried in many ways but nothing worked.

Comment: It starts with an outline heart then on hover it change and fill with a color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call jQuery methods on a DOM object.

Instead of targetting the DOM object `this`, you're looking to chain `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` to the **jQuery wrapper** `$(this)`:

```js
$("span").filter(".fa.fa-heart-o").hover(function() {
  //alert("hola");
  $(this).removeClass('fa fa-heart-o');
  $(this).addClass('fa fa-heart');
}, function() {
  //alert("adios");
  $(this).removeClass('fa fa-heart');
  $(this).addClass('fa fa-heart-o');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing and adding a class we can simply use `attr()` function of jQuery to change the class to desired one like below

```
$("span").filter(".fa.fa-heart-o").hover(function() {
  $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-heart');
}, function() {
  $(this).attr('class', 'fa fa-heart-o');
});
```